# Flow type for an array of HTML elements?

Tags: flowtype

I'm converting some working JavaScript code to Flow. I have a variable `IMAGES` which is created but not immediately assigned any value. Later on it becomes an array of HTML elements.

Why is this code wrong?

```
let IMAGES Array<HTMLElement>;

// Later on within an init function: 
IMAGES = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.${someImagesClass}`));
```

The Flow error I get is:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Comment: Is this the actual code? Line 1 has a typo because it's missing the colon `:` between the variable identifier and the Flow type.

Answer (score 3):

All I was missing was the `:`

```
let IMAGES: Array<HTMLElement>;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no generic-syntax and no need to "publish" a variable in JavaScript! Just merge both:

```
// Later on within an init function: 
let IMAGES = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.${someImagesClass}`));
```

Comment: My question is about Flow types not regular JavaScript. Also I simplified my code, in actually fact IMAGES is assigned within an init function.